# Setting subcaption width for specific subcaptions

Tags: subfloats, width, subcaption

In the `subfig` packge, the command `\captionsetup[subfigure]{width=<length>}` can set the width of all subcaptions within a figure.

How can the width of just a single subcaption in a figure be set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using grouping should do it:

```
\begin{figure}
\begingroup
\captionsetup[subfigure]{width=<length>}
\subfloat[<caption>}{ .... }
\endgroup
%
\subfloat[<caption>}{ .... }
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Is this grouping something that can be done in all of LaTeX or does it come with subfig?

Comment: It can be done with everything in (La)TeX. Note that `\begin{..}` and `\end{..}` already add group, so any LaTeX environment would do as well. Also some settings like counters are done global so grouping won't effect them.

Comment: And what if I want the subfloat to be centered above the caption?

Comment: Try `justification=centering,singlelinecheck=false,position=top` as options.

Comment: This justifies the text but does nothing to the subfloat.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood it that you wanted the caption centered on top of the subfloat. I would have to check the manual for this. Feel free to ask this as new question.

Comment: Done: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23710/center-subfloat-above-extended-subcaption-in-subfig-package