# Center subfloat above extended subcaption in subfig package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats, width, subcaption

In the subfig package, the command `\captionsetup[subfigure]{width=<length>}` extends the width of a subcaption. Now how can the subfloats be centered above their enlarged subcaptions? The subfloats appear to be left justified by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could put the subfigure object into a `\makebox[<width>][c]{...}` via a macro:

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{width=5em}
\newcommand{\includesubfig}[2][]{%
  \makebox[5em][c]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}%
```

and then use

```
\subfloat[ToC-entry][This is a very long subcaption that should span a couple of lines]%
  {\includesubfig{fig}}%
```

Here is a draft of what it looks like where my figure consists of `\rule{20pt}{30pt}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{width=5em}
\begin{document}
  ​\begin{figure}
    \subfloat[test1][This is a very long caption that should span over a couple of lines]{\makebox[5em][c]{\rule{20pt}{30pt}}}
    \caption{This is caption for the figure}
  \end{figure}
​\end{document}​​​​​​​
```

[image: Centered subfloat/subfigure]

Alternatively, if you only do this for limited number of subfigures, then manually using the `\makebox[<width>][c]{...}` should suffice, as I did in the minimal example above.

Comment: Your picture is exactly what I am looking for but copy/pasting your code didn't give me something like that...it gave me [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/123623/Stack%20Exchange/figure_not_centered.pdf).

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the minimal example I used to reproduce the graphic. It works for me - centering the subfloat - even if I just use the word `figure` for my graphic.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out my problem. First, I put whole subfloat into the makebox instead of just the figure inside the subfloat (that seems obvious now). Second, the width parameter of the makebox needs to match the width parameter of the subcaption (also seems fairly obvious now).

Comment: @Tyson: Yes, the lengths should be the same. You could have a central location for updating this length by defining: `\newlength{\subfigwidth}\setlength{subfigwidth}{5em}` and then using `\subfigwidth` instead of the fixed `5em`. This allows you to have one location that updates all references to the subfigure widths.